# Remove entire line if it does not contain a phrase

Tags: java, string

I have string that looks like the following, and I would like to go through and delete lines that don't contain the tags _JJ or _NN.

input:

```
Hello_NN
and_CC
Happy_JJ
Birthday_NN
to_TO
me_NN
!_!
```

output:

```
Hello_NN
Happy_JJ
Birthday_NN
me_NN
```

Comment: tried using the replaceAll method with a regex, would that work in a situation like this?

Comment: post the attempted code that didnt work & explain any issues

Comment: How is the question unclear? He said he has a string and posted the contents, and he's wondering how to transform it into the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

1) Create a loop that processes each line.

2) In the loop, use the String.contains() function to see if the line contains "_JJ" or "_NN"

3) If the condition fails, skip that line.

4) If the condition passes, output that line.

---

Method 2:

Fiddle at regex101.com until you get a working regex:

`foo = bar.replaceAll( "(?m)^.+(?<!JJ|NN)(\n|$)", "" );`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add the rows you want to a new string, rather than deleting from the one you already have:

```
String newOutput = "";
while(! endOfInput){ // While you have stuff to read
   String temp = input.readLine(); // Get line
   if(temp.contains("_JJ") || temp.contains("_NN"){ // If the line contains something we want to keep
      newOutput += temp + "\n"; // Add it to new output, with new line marker
   }
}
// Display new output here.
```